# PostgreSQL hangs during shut down in linux?

Tags: postgresql

I m using PostgreSQL 9.0. It hangs during shutdown.
when I used `pg_ctl stop` it hangs and after sometime its displaying msg:

```
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

and when I used psql its showing:

```
psql: FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
```

and in logs its writing these msgs

```
 DEBUG:  postmaster received signal 15
2011-07-14 09:36:00 ETC/GMT LOG:  received smart shutdown request
```

Please tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: Which distribution of GNU/Linux you have ? @Magnus is right about smart and fast shutdown. You might read more about it in doc (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-shutdown.html). It's pretty well explained there.

Answer (score 11):

By default, `pg_ctl` will attempt a "smart shutdown". This shutdown will tell the system not to accept any new connections, but not shut down until existing ones have disconnected.

You probably want to use "fast" shutdown (by executing `pg_ctl -m fast`), which will also disconnect existing users.

For Debian (`pg_ctl` is not by default on `$PATH`):

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.4 main restart -m fast
```

Answer (score 4):

A regular shutdown request will wait until all connections are terminated.

When `pg_ctl stop` "hangs", it means you still have open connections to the database. Shut down all applications that connect to that server and then Postgres should shut down normally.

The error "the database system is shutting down" comes from the fact that Postgres is trying to shutdown and thereofor does not allow any new connections.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to identify what's going on, you can log in via `psql` and type:

```
test=> SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
 datid | datname | procpid | usesysid |   usename    | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          | waiting |          current_query          
-------+---------+---------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------
 18703 | test |    7604 |    18702 | test_sean | psql             |             |                 |          -1 | 2011-07-14 07:23:40.021921+00 |                               | 2011-07-14 07:23:46.398894+00 | f       | <IDLE>
 18703 | test |    7673 |    18702 | test_sean | psql             |             |                 |          -1 | 2011-07-14 07:24:54.507982+00 | 2011-07-14 07:25:00.102369+00 | 2011-07-14 07:25:00.102369+00 | f       | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That's going to be hard, since the system is in shutdown mode...

Comment: Quite so. The above will at least give the questioner the ability to dig in at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely want to use pg_ctl, why not use the following  instead :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1 stop
```

The init.d scripts issues :

```
$SU -l postgres -c "$PGENGINE/pg_ctl stop -D '$PGDATA' -s -m fast" > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

This is a fast shutdown and performs what you need.